# Cyclic executive scheduling

Tags: embedded, task, scheduled-tasks, real-time, scheduling

[image: cyclic_executive]

Figure shows a model of a real-time application.

The system consumes
periodically the inputs **X** and **Y** and produces the output **Z**. The inputs **X** and **Y**
are not updated simultaneously, but input **Y** is delayed `500ms` compared with
input **X**. Also the subsystems **A**, **B** and **C** have different execution times (eA ≈
100ms, eB ≈ 200ms, eC ≈ 200ms).

How ever I don't understand the  correct functionality of the application.

I have so far understood that the subtask A,B and C has the following period and execution time

A(0,100)

B(600, 200)

C(800,200)

But I don't understand how to sketch the table for this and how to handle the execution times and periods for the X and Y and for the subsystem A,B and C.
Any hint would be great thanks

Comment: And how is this related to Ada?

Comment: Probably via the Burns&Welling book ... which should answer this question.

Comment: @egilhh i have changed the title now.

Comment: What does `A(0,100)` mean? Specifically what is the zero?  "Sketching" sounds like design not implementation and may be off-topic.  I suggest you draw a timing diagram. Also the frequency of arrival of data is irrelevant if A and B run periodically and asynchronously to the data availability - A and B either run event-driven in response arrival of X and Y or they poll X and Y periodically.  Your description appears  to conflate the two.